# an example of async/await in javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I am studying async and await in javascript, and a little bit confused about the execution order of the following function I wrote when I play around async and await:

```
const promiseA = new Promise((resolutionFunc, rejectionFunc) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolutionFunc(666), 5000);
});

const test = async () => {
  await promiseA.then((val) =>
    console.log("asynchronous logging has val:", val)
  );
};

const testTwo = () => {
  test();
  console.log("immediate logging");
};

testTwo();
```

my understand is that in function <testTwo()>, <test()> execute first, it's been called & executed,  <test()> is an async function, and I have put the await in front of the promise.

why this `console.log("immediate logging");` line of code get executed first?

on the other hand, if I wrote <testTwo()> like following:

```
const testTwo = async () => {
  await test();
  console.log("immediate logging");
};
```

everything is fine

Comment: When you call test synchronously the asynchronous operations get put into what's called the *event loop*. All the synchronous operations that follow will run before the pending resolutions of the asynchronous operations in the event loop. So you see the synchronous logging... then the event loop runs the promise resolutions. If you use the await, the code after gets run after the resolution

Comment: It seems you already know why it's executed before the asynchronous log from `test()`: because you didn't `await` it?

Comment: Would it help your understanding if you put a `console.log("Starting test");` in the first line of the `test` function?